# Looking inside the content of an array PHP/Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, switch-statement

I have this code on PHP:

```
for($number=0; $number<=9;$number++)
    {
        switch($twigparams["entries"][$number]["continent"])
        {
            case "Europe" : $europeanusers+=1;
            break;
            case "Asia" : $asiaticusers+=1;
            break;
            case "Africa" : $africanusers+=1;
            break;
            case "America" : $americanusers+=1;
            break;
            case "Oceania" : $oceanicusers+=1;
            break;
            default;
        }
}
```

If I do:

```
echo $twigparams["entries"][$number]["continent"];
```

inside the for loop, that show the currently continent, but the switch does not work, always goes to the default case and no one of the options it's increased.

Here is the var_dump of the first two elements of `$twigparams`:

```
array(3) {
    ["option"]=> int(0)
    ["entries"]=> array(10) {
        [0]=> array(5) {
            ["name"]=> string(10) "Federico "
            ["typeofcontract"]=> string(18) "Voice + Internet "
            ["gender"]=> string(6) "Male " 
            ["age"]=> string(4) "54 " 
            ["continent"]=> string(6) "Asia " 
        }
        [1]=> array(5) {
            ["name"]=> string(7) "Maria "
            ["typeofcontract"]=> string(18) "Voice + Internet "
            ["gender"]=> string(8) "Female "
            ["age"]=> string(4) "32 "
            ["continent"]=> string(9) "America " 
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what is the problem and I can't reproduce it, but instead of writing `$europeanusers+=1;` since you want to increment, use the incrementation syntax: `$europeanusers++;`. As an aside, using a `if...elseif` is faster than a `switch/case`

Comment: Can you do a var_dump( $twigparams) just to see its structure

Comment: Are your variables `$xxxxusers` references to your array `$twigparams`? Otherwise the `$twigparams` array isn't supposed to change.

Comment: The var_dump($twigparams) is crazy, because I have stored there everything. 

 I think it's a problem of conversion reading the value of:
 
$twigparams["entries"][$number]["continent"]

Something with the switch, who can not read all the characters or sth... because I tried to put into the switch, in the cases: "America ", " America" and all the possibles cases with the space " " and is not working...

And yes, the variables are referenced correctly.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Have you initialized all the variables to 0:  `$europeanusers`, `$asiaticusers`, etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a trailing space on your array values.  Simply apply `trim()` to the switch statement.  I have also swapped in `foreach()` because it should be more flexible with future array changed, and I've shown the `++` incrementing.

```
$twigparams=array(
    "option"=>array(0),
    "entries"=>array(
        0=>array(
            "name"=>"Federico ",
            "typeofcontract"=>"Voice + Internet ",
            "gender"=>"Male ",
            "age"=>"54 ",
            "continent"=>"Asia "
        ),
        1=>array(
            "name"=>"Maria ",
            "typeofcontract"=>"Voice + Internet ",
            "gender"=>"Female ",
            "age"=>"32 ",
            "continent"=>"America "
        )
    )
);

$europeanusers=0;
$asiaticusers=0;
$africanusers=0;
$americanusers=0;
$oceanicusers=0;

foreach($twigparams["entries"] as $a){
    switch(trim($a["continent"])){
        case "Europe" : ++$europeanusers;
        break;
        case "Asia" : ++$asiaticusers;
        break;
        case "Africa" : ++$africanusers;
        break;
        case "America" : ++$americanusers;
        break;
        case "Oceania" : ++$oceanicusers;
        break;
        default;
    }
}

echo "EUROPE: $europeanusers<br>";
echo "ASIA: $asiaticusers<br>";
echo "AFRICA: $africanusers<br>";
echo "AMERICA: $americanusers<br>";
echo "OCEANIA: $oceanicusers<br>";
```

Output:

```
EUROPE: 0
ASIA: 1
AFRICA: 0
AMERICA: 1
OCEANIA: 0
```

Comment: Now it's perfect! Thank you so much for your help, I voted you with green! :)